# Struts 2 <s:doubleselect> Tag Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'applicant_jobTitle' of undefined

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I have a dynamically populated list for both drop-downs. The **first dropdown** let's you select job area lists while the **second dropdown** will dynamically populate acccordingly to the selected option of first dropdown. If i use this tag to save data everything is fine but If I use this to edit an existing data, the second dropdown never drops an options. I think there's a problem when struts 2 wants to give value to **second dropdown**. And i found this error under web console.

"**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'applicant_jobTitle' of undefined**"

This is my jsp

```
<s:doubleselect label="Job Applied"  required="true" 
 headerKey="-1"   headerValue="Select Job Area" 
       name="applicant.jobArea"          list="listJobArea.keySet()      
 doubleName="applicant.jobTitle"   doubleList="listJobArea.get(top)"     
 formName="formApplicant"/>
```

This is my html

```
<form action="updateApplicant" class="class java.util.HashMap" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

```
<p>
<s:hidden cssClass="textfield" name="applicant.applicantNo" />
<s:hidden cssClass="textfield" name="applicant.dateAdded" />
<s:hidden cssClass="textfield" name="applicant.status" />
</p>
<p>
<s:textfield cssClass="textfield" name="applicant.firstName" required= "true"
    label="Firstname" />
</p>
<p>
<s:textfield cssClass="textfield" name="applicant.lastName" required= "true"
    label="Lastname" />
</p>
<br>
<p>
<s:textfield cssClass="textfield" required= "true" name="applicant.email" label="Email" />
</p>
<br>
<p>
<s:textfield cssClass="textfield" name="applicant.contactNo" required= "true"
    label="Contact Number" />
</p>
<br>
<s:doubleselect label="Job Applied"  required="true" 
        headerKey="-1"   headerValue="Select Job Area" 
          name="applicant.jobArea"          list="listJobArea.keySet()      
         doubleName="applicant.jobTitle"   doubleList="listJobArea.get(top)"     
        formName="formApplicant"/>
```

```
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="action:cancel" value="Cancel" >    
    <input value="Update" type="submit" name="submit" />
```

This is the auto-generated javasript from doubleselect struts 2 tag

The error will show in line --> **applicant_jobAreaRedirect(1);**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var applicant_jobAreaGroup = new Array(2 + 1);
for (i = 0; i < (2 + 1); i++)
applicant_jobAreaGroup[i] = new Array();

applicant_jobAreaGroup[1][0] = new Option("Select Job Title", "Select Job Title");

applicant_jobAreaGroup[1][1] = new Option("Application Architect", "Application Architect");

applicant_jobAreaGroup[1][2] = new Option("Business Architect", "Business Architect");

applicant_jobAreaGroup[2][0] = new Option("Select Job Title", "Select Job Title");

applicant_jobAreaGroup[2][1] = new Option("Application Consultant", "Application Consultant");

applicant_jobAreaGroup[2][2] = new Option("Engagement Manager", "Engagement Manager");

applicant_jobAreaGroup[2][3] = new Option("General Other Consultant", "General Other Consultant");


var applicant_jobAreaTemp = document.formApplicant.applicant_jobTitle;
applicant_jobAreaRedirect(1);
function applicant_jobAreaRedirect(x) {
    var selected = false;
    for (m = applicant_jobAreaTemp.options.length - 1; m >= 0; m--) {
        applicant_jobAreaTemp.options[m] = null;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < applicant_jobAreaGroup[x].length; i++) {
        applicant_jobAreaTemp.options[i] = new Option(applicant_jobAreaGroup[x][i].text, applicant_jobAreaGroup[x][i].value);
            if (applicant_jobAreaTemp.options[i].value == 'Application Architect') {
                applicant_jobAreaTemp.options[i].selected = true;
                selected = true;
            }
    }

    if ((applicant_jobAreaTemp.options.length > 0) && (! selected)) {
        applicant_jobAreaTemp.options[0].selected = true;
    }
}
```

Is there a problem to my doubleselect tag or a way to edit this javascript?
or how to edit or get the `double.ftl`?

Comment: Can you post a relevant HTML code?

Comment: Ok i'll added the html code @RomanC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just added the name of my form just i did on my jsp..Looks like i forgot to put it.